# SQL QUERY for finding set of highest numbers

Tags: sql

how to get top 1,00,000 customers name and email id who have booked maximum number of tickets? The table has columns like:
NAME, CUST_ID, JOINING DATE, NO. OF TICKETS BOOKED, EMAIL_ID.

Comment: No effort shown + No database mentioned

Comment: you could have easily got the answer by a simple google search - check this  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 100000 NAME, CUST_ID, [JOINING DATE], [NO. OF TICKETS BOOKED], EMAIL_ID
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
ORDER BY  [NO. OF TICKETS BOOKED] DESC
```

Are you looking for this ?

if you are working with SQL SERVER

Comment: Your sql syntax looks like TSQL why not MySQL syntax?

Comment: @rekire where does he said he want a mysql query ?

Comment: `TOP` is not supported by all the databases - you should have mentioned while giving answer like concerning which DB u have given the answer

Comment: I'm just wondering. My point is just it may not work on other DBMS.

Comment: @rekire: Duely noted :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work if you are using Microsoft Sql server (tsql)

```
    Select TOP 120 columns FROM table ORDER BY columns desc
```

Comment: Your sql syntax looks like TSQL why not MySQL syntax?

Comment: `TOP` is not supported by all the databases - you should have mentioned while giving answer like concerning which DB u have given the answer

Comment: Yes, could not see any tag or indication in the question so just took a guess. Thanks have updated,should have done it first time:)